# Unable to get right units when decorating a class constructor with pint

Tags: python, pint

I was trying the following code,

```
from pint import UnitRegistry

ureg = UnitRegistry()
Q_ = ureg.Quantity

class Simple:
    @ureg.wraps(None, (None, None, 'm**3'), True)
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def calculate(self):
        return self.a*self.b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = Simple(2, Q_(20, 'm**3')).calculate()
    print c
```

which gives the output,

```
40.0
```

This is a float type. Is there a way to instead automatically output a pint Quantity object with magnitude and correct units, i.e. 40.0 m**3?

Thanks

Comment: You would presumably also have to wrap `calculate`, I doubt `pint` will follow those attributes through the class.

Comment: That works. I was hoping that the class variables 'self.a' and 'self.b' would be Quantity objects (which they are not), and hence the result of their multiplication would also be a Quantity object that would be returned.